# I have the code to make an imageview rounded, now I want to use a background

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

I have this code that makes an imageview's border now I want that imageview get a picture too.

now how can I edit this code to include an image too?

Comment: why dont you set the image in the imageview itself.

Comment: See the solution posted below. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/my_imageView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp" 
     android:background="@drawable/rounded_imageview"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

EDIT:

OR

```
ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);
myimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Both way you can do that.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You coud use this method to get Rouded corners

```
BitmapShader shader;
shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setShader(shader);

RectF rect = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);

// rect contains the bounds of the shape
// radius is the radius in pixels of the rounded corners
// paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);
```

Easily you could add more features to the imageview in this way